# Save google maps markers locally

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-markers

building a map (using html and JS) with several markers, different labels and colors, it takes time to use google function
**http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/color.png**
Is that possible to store and use local png images, or, better to save image code (eg base64) into vars ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean ? Do you want to use your own image for the `icon` property when you construct a new `google.maps.Marker` object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is, in the main loop where you are defining markers, use something like this and that will work:

```
marker[ i ] = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng ),
    title: krexmap[ i ].title,
    icon: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh...",
});
```

Icon, can be a `url` path but for sure you can also use `datauri`.

Note: I took that code from my project